# camel spring ws - Error during type conversion from type: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: apache-camel, spring-ws

I tried to create a web service with camel and spring-ws as per the site  - http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html

But when I am firing the soap request I am getting below error

```
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode>ns0:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">Error during type conversion from type: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream to the required type: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader with value java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@65422509 due java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Exception in console

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:82) ~[?:1.6.0_45]
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamInputFactory.java:66) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.stax_1.10.0.0.jar:1.10.0.0]
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxp.StaxConverter.createXMLStreamReader(StaxConverter.java:170) ~[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[?:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[?:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[?:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.invokeMethod(ObjectHelper.java:990) ~[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.InstanceMethodTypeConverter.convertTo(InstanceMethodTypeConverter.java:78) ~[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.doConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:275) ~[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.convertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:113) ~[camel-core-2.12.2.jar:2.12.2]
    ... 36 more
```

I am building the application in jdk 8, but with source and target set to 1.6 in maven as I will be deploying in server with 1.6 only

Router builder and the spring servlet context xml is put below

```
@Component    
public class CamelTestServiceRoute extends RouteBuilder {
@Autowired
private TestMessageProcessor testMessageProcessor;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    //JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(false);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat jxbdf = 
            new org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);
    //jaxb.setContextPath(jaxbContext);
    from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://www.prxms.ws/service}CamelTestServiceRequest?endpointMapping=#camelEndpointMapper")
    .unmarshal(jxbdf)
    .process(testMessageProcessor)
    .marshal(jxbdf);
   }
}
```

spring servlet xml content

```
<sws:annotation-driven />

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="testservice" portTypeName="TestService"
    locationUri="/testService/" targetNamespace="http://www.prxms.ws/definitions">
    <sws:xsd location="/schemas/service.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
    <camel:contextScan />
</camel:camelContext>


<bean id="payLoadMapper"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />

<bean id="camelEndpointMapper"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.bean.CamelEndpointMapping" />

<bean id="camelEndpointAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MessageEndpointAdapter" />
```

maven dependencies

```
   <properties>
      <spring-ws-version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring-ws-version>
      <camel-spring-version>2.12.2</camel-spring-version>
      <spring-test-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-test-version>
      <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-ws-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

Can somebody help

Comment: Are you deploying your app into any application server? Which (with version)? And do you have any exception in log?

Comment: I am deploying to weblogic 10.3.6 with jdk 1.6. I am not getting any error in console. I am only able to see the error as part of the soap response..

Comment: I have another normal spring ws endpoint in same code with different Payload which is working fine. The camel one is only giving error..

Comment: Wild guess: the Camel exchange property (Exchange.CHARSET_NAME) is null while convert byte array to string require character encoding (e.g. UTF-8)

Comment: Managed to print the exception stacktrace in console. Added above

Comment: To debug, the first step is to locate your problem location. Add some log in between each step of your route and check which one is returning this error.

Comment: It was an issue with camel 2.12.2 version - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7025. I upgraded to 2.12.3 but other issues are coming. Seems the 2.12.x version of camel has many incompatibility with jdk 1.6

Comment: Latest issue is  - [http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-XmlConverter-after-upgrade-to-2-12-3-td5748082.html]